# Sending additional data to Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'd like to send some additional information to Automapper so I can use them in the `CreateMap`. It seems that I have to use `MappingOperatingOption` and `Items`.

So my call is like this:

```
var obj = Mapper.Map<class>(x, o => o.Items.Add("data", 23));
```

The problem is that I cannot access that value in the `MapFrom`.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>()
                .ForMember(x => x.FieldA, o => o.MapFrom(d => 
                    //accessing item here))
```

There's very little documentation about Automapper and I didn't come up with anything, any guidance is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ResolveUsing` instead of `MapFrom` like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.FieldA,
        opt =>
            opt.ResolveUsing((resolution_result, src) =>
                (int)resolution_result.Context.Options.Items["data"] + src.FieldB));
```

I am using `(int)resolution_result.Context.Options.Items["data"] + src.FieldB` just as an example here. You can read any piece of data from `resolution_result.Context.Options.Items` and use it as you like.

Comment: Using `ResolveUsing` gives me `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Type' because it is not a delegate` compile error. I'm using this code: .`ForMember(x => x.FieldA, o => o.ResolveUsing((result, src) => 23))`

Comment: If you simply want to return `23` why do you need to use `ResolveUsing`?

Comment: No, that was a sample, I need to call a function! ;)

Comment: ForMember(x => x.FieldA, o => o.ResolveUsing((result, src) => StaticClass.StaticFunc(src.FieldA, src.FieldB, (long)result.Context.Options.Items["data"] ) ))

Comment: What version of AutoMapper are you using? Does the `StaticClass.StaticFunc` method have a return type that is the same as the type of ClassA.FieldA?

Comment: I'm not sure about version and I don't have access to it right now, but they're types are the same.